# Why Does the Div Wrapper Alter My Page In This Way?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I comment out my Div wrapper, the page becomes a jumbled mess, if the wrapper is not commented out, it is not a jumbled mess.

Why? My guess is that is is somehow shielded from the CSS, but I am not sure.

I am new so, I apologize in advance.

This exercise is part of the OdinProject, and is the first one I'm actually struggling with understanding.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

body {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background: #aaa;
  color: #333;
  /* I'll give you this one for free lol */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal {
  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;
  padding: 16px;
  background: white;
  width: 480px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.icon {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  color: royalblue;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: lavender;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.close-button {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

button.continue {
  background: royalblue;
  border: 1px solid royalblue;
  color: white;
}

button.cancel {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: royalblue;
}

.text {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="icon">!</div>


  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">Are you sure you want to do that?
      <div class="close-button">✖</div>
    </div>


    <div class="text">text</div>
    <button class="continue">Continue</button>
    <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: you have no `=` in your wrapper class declaration. `class "wrapper"` != `class="wrapper"

Comment: @Yong that typo has already been corrected by the OP. Please remove the comment voluntarily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.modal` has the `display: flex` property. This property applies to all direct children of the `.modal` element.

If you remove the `.wrapper`, the elements in the modal are no longer grouped together and they are treated as separate flex items. This is why they appear side to side (`.icon`, then `.header`, then `.text`, then `.button` all on the same line).

Here is a [great guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on the `display: flex` property.

Answer (score -1):

All HTML elements have default properties. A `div` has one: `display: block;`. In this case, when your wrapper div is removed, this property is removed it breaks the appearance because this default is battling the parent element's `display: flex` property.

Here's the default property list: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp